# Split a string into its sentences using python

Tags: python, string

I have this following string:

```
string = 'This is one sentence  ${w_{1},..,w_{i}}$. This is another sentence. '
```

Now, I want to split it into two sentence.

However, when I do:

```
string.split('.')
```

I get:

```
['This is one sentence  ${w_{1},',
 '',
 ',w_{i}}$',
 ' This is another sentence',
 ' ']
```

Anyone has an idea of how to improve it, in order to not detect the "." within the `$ $` ?

Also, how would you go about this:

```
string2 = 'This is one sentence  ${w_{1},..,w_{i}}$! This is another sentence. Is this a sentence? Maybe !  '
```

**EDIT 1:**

The desired outputs would be:

For string 1:

```
['This is one sentence  ${w_{1},..,w_{i}}$','This is another sentence']
```

For string 2:

```
['This is one sentence  ${w_{1},..,w_{i}}$','This is another sentence', 'Is this a sentence', 'Maybe !  ']
```

Comment: What would your desired output be?

Comment: One thing you should consider is that in LaTeX, the proper ellipsis is `\ldots`, not `...`.

Comment: You're setting `.` as your delimiter, which is why it will split up your string at every `.` it finds, regardless of its context within the string.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Yes, definitely. I will change that. However, the question still remains, since I have other cases, where I cannot simply replace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the more general case, you could use `re.split` like so:

```py
import re

mystr = 'This is one sentence  ${w_{1},..,w_{i}}$. This is another sentence. '

re.split("[.!?]\s{1,}", mystr)
# ['This is one sentence  ${w_{1},..,w_{i}}$', 'This is another sentence', '']

str2 = 'This is one sentence  ${w_{1},..,w_{i}}$! This is another sentence. Is this a sentence? Maybe !  '

re.split("[.!?]\s{1,}", str2)
['This is one sentence  ${w_{1},..,w_{i}}$', 'This is another sentence', 'Is this a sentence', 'Maybe ', '']
```

Where the chars in the brackets are what you pick as your punctuation, and you add at least one space at the end `\s{1,}` to ignore the other `.`'s, which have no spacing. This will also handle your exclamation point case

Here's a (somewhat hacky) way to get the punctuation back

```py
punct = re.findall("[.!?]\s{1,}", str2)
['! ', '. ', '? ', '!  ']

sent = [x+y for x,y in zip(re.split("[.!?]\s{1,}", str2), punct)]
sent
['This is one sentence  ${w_{1},..,w_{i}}$! ', 'This is another sentence. ', 'Is this a sentence? ', 'Maybe !  ']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and especially for your last hack ! Really cool ! +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.findall` with an alternation pattern. To ensure that the sentence starts and ends with a non-whitespace, use a positive lookahead pattern at the start and a positive lookbehind pattern at the end:

```
re.findall(r'((?=[^.!?\s])(?:$.*?\$|[^.!?])*(?<=[^.!?\s]))\s*[.!?]', string)
```

This returns, for the first string:

```
['This is one sentence  ${w_{1},..,w_{i}}$', 'This is another sentence']
```

and for the second string:

```
['This is one sentence  ${w_{1},', ',w_{i}}$', 'This is another sentence', 'Is this a sentence', 'Maybe']
```

Comment: Very nice  ! Thanks a lot for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Use '. ' (with a space after the .) because that only exists when a sentence ends, not mid-sentence.

```
string = 'This is one sentence  ${w_{1},..,w_{i}}$. This is another sentence. '

string.split('. ')
```

this returns:

['This is one sentence  ${w_{1},..,w_{i}}$', 'This is another sentence', '']

Comment: Good idea ! But what about if the sentences have bad formatting ? Maybe one could just ignore everything that is between `$ $`?

Comment: Im not sure. You could ensure that all sentences have correct formatting so that when one sentence ends (with a .) there is a space afterwards before the next sentence begins. This way there will never be bad formatting. Is that possible for your code?